# Javascript Changing inputted word based on function

Tags: javascript, function

Expected Output
Example: Our word is Pokemon

Pokemon (Regular word)

P!k!m!n (Every 2nd letter is !)

Nomekop (Reversed)

pokemOn (Every 6th letter is uppercase)

[Array of ASCII Values]

I am sure that I have got reverse just fine but need help in figuring out uppercase and changing every 2nd letter and returning ASCII codes of the word.

I would imagine that the logic for replacing is where i%2 = 0 make the character a '!'
If uppercase is similar I am struggling to implement it or I could be wrong.

The output looks like this right now

Pokemon
undefined
Pokemon
80
nomekop

```
function replaceAt(string) {
  for(let i=0; i=string.length; i++){
    string = word
    string.charAt(i) = '!'
    i++
  }
}

// This function intended to make every 6th letter uppercase
function capitalizeFirstLetter(string) {
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
  }

function returnASCII(string) {
  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    // How to do this but on one line?
    // Would I have to convert this to an array?
    return string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
}

let word = "Pokemon";
console.log(word)
console.log(replaceAt(1, "!"))
console.log(capitalizeFirstLetter(word));
console.log(returnASCII(word))

// Intended to show word reversed
let reverse = word.split('').reverse().join('').toLowerCase();
console.log(reverse)
```

I am only concerned with vanilla JS

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ReplaceAt

For replaceAt, you're passing two parameters, but you only set up your function with one.

### Capitalize Every 6th Letter

To capitalize every 6th letter of a word, do this:

```
function capitalizeEvery6thLetter(word){
    res = '';
    for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
        if((i % 5) == 0){ // Check i % 5 instead of 6 due to zero indexing
            res += word[i].toUpperCase();
        } else {
          res += word[i]
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Iterate through the word, check if i%5 is 0 (due to every 5th index actually being the 6th letter), set that letter to uppercase and add it to an empty result string, or just add the letter if it i%5 isn't 0. Then once all the letters are added, return the result.

### Word to ASCII Array

For turning a word into an array of ASCII characters, do this:

```
function asciiValues(word){
  res = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
      res.push(word[i].charCodeAt())
  }
  return res;
}
```

It's a similar approach to the last function, only get the character code at each letter and add it to an array. In your current function, you have a correct set up, but the return statement of the loop means it only runs once before returning the single letter to ascii.

Comment: Thanks! It works so far. By two parameters for replaceAt do you mean `    string = word
string.charAt(i) = '!'

Comment: No problem! For the replaceAt, I mean your function's set up like this: `function replaceAt(string) {`, so it's only meant to take one variable, but you pass in 1 and "!" when you call it. Maybe you could change the set up to something like this: `function replaceAt(string, index, character) {`. Then you can pass in your word, the index to change, and the character to replace it with.